# How do I check virtualbox version from CLI

Tags: bash, virtualbox

I am writing a Bash script to store the version number of **Virtualbox**, but cannot succeed.

My Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
installed_virtualbox=$(virtualbox --version) # --version this is what I want to change
```

I tried

```
virtualbox --version
virtualbox -v
virtualbox -V
virtualbox --Version
```

all seems to open the virtualbox instead of output.
`virtualbox --help` gives the version number, but the output is too long to store in variable and use later.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To print or view the current **VirtualBox** version you should use below command:

```
vboxmanage --version
```

which will then print the current version as seen below;

[image]

Refer [**8.2. Command overview**](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp52704112) at the official VirtualBox site for more.

---

To print the version using the script, see below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(vboxmanage --version)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `echo $(vboxmanage --version | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}')` and `echo $(vboxmanage --version)` what is the difference? are not they same?

Comment: @souravc -- In your comment here, you use `--version`, which outputs only one line and one field; so using `head` and `awk` to trim is redundant, and yes they output the same result. In your answer below, you use `--help` instead of `--version`, in which case `head` and `awk` trimming is indeed necessary... but you still get less-precise information, as the version found via `--help` is only #.#.# vs `--version` which yields #.#.#r# (version with revision info).

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn you are correct now it is unnecessary. At that time `vboxmanage` used to come with some other info that is why I proposed that. You can [see the edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/420370/revisions), OP accepted my suggestion. Why would I make things complex:)

Comment: @souravc -- Ahhh... funny how context makes things clearer. :-P So... excellent tip. :-)

Comment: Since VBox 5.0, `vbox-img --version` can print version as well.

Comment: On my OS `VBoxManage` is case sensitive, so `vboxmanage` does not actually work.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this,

```
virtualbox --help | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

or

```
$ echo $(virtualbox --help | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}')
4.3.6
```

**How it works**

**Step -1**

`virtualbox --help`

gives you a long output saying many options etc. But its very first lines are like,

> Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.3.6
>   (C) 2005-2013 Oracle Corporation
>   All rights reserved.
>   ...

**Step -2**

`| head -n 1`

`|` is called pipe. It has great application in command line. It passes the whole expression to the next command `head`. `head -n 1` prints the first line only. see `man head` for more. At this stage output is only

> Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.3.6

**Step -3**

`| awk '{print $NF}'`

Again the remaining things are passed to `awk`. At this stage `awk` sees the whole line as combinations of few fields separated by space and prints only the last field of the above expression. So you get the version only. See `man awk` for more.

Comment: Would be great if you could breakdown the command and explain what each part does.

Comment: @Jobin plz see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

you could know the version of package installed with dpkg and grep with piping

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: What does each of these piped commands do, please be verbose.

Answer (score 1):

```
avi@avi-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ virtualbox --help
Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.3.6
```

So run the below command,

```
virtualbox --help | awk '/Oracle/{ print $5 }'
```

Output:

```
4.3.6
```

`awk '/Oracle/{ print $5 }'`

Searches for the line which consists of the word `Oracle` .If yes then the command picks up the fifth column on that line and redirects it to standard output.If no such word was present on any lines,then it displays nothing.